# Getting data from post request in GWT client

Tags: java, gwt, http-post

I am trying to handle POST request in GWT. I did that in server side, but, i feel its work will be fine if the POST request is handled in client side. I was able to complete GET request in client side by reading the query string. But in case of POST, a file is being sent. How can i able to get the file from POST request in GWT client.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

handling post request in GWT client is not possible. refer :
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/LOWMIPYcd7A